# How to create an app (such as .apk or .exe) that communicates to web server

Tags: python, web-applications, communication

This is my first post. I tried to google and find my own solution, but I don’t even know where to start with this. I want to make a phone app (with `Unity(C#)` ideally) and eventually a website, while also hosting a web app (`python`) that the phone app can send basic info (ideally a json or dict) that the web app can do some processing and database referencing and just send back a short answer or two (again ideally a json or dict). I looked into `bottlepy` and just communicating through `http` but this seems clunky and I’m sure is not the best way. I don't need (although would appreciate) a full explanation, just the term/protocol/technology I am looking for. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the UnityWebRequest : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html

And maybe you should try to use a REST API on your server to communicate with a UnityWebRequest : https://codetolight.wordpress.com/2017/01/18/unity-rest-api-interaction-with-unitywebrequest-and-besthttp/